# How to sort a two-dimensional array in descending order of matching values

Tags: javascript

I have 2 arrays

```
var first = ['a', 'b', 'c',]
var second = [ 
            {'value' : ['a', 'b']},
            {'value' : ['c', 'e']},
            {'value' : ['a', 'c', 'b']},
            {'value' : ['f']}, 
          ]
```

How do I get this?

```
third:   [ 
            {'value' : ['a', 'c', 'b']},
            {'value' : ['a','b']}, 
            {'value' : ['c', 'e']},
          ]
```

Now I'm doing this

some returns true if the function returned true for at least one argument, and false otherwise

so I'm looking for a match between two arrays

```
second.filter(item => first.some(num => item.value.includes(num)))
*            {'value' : ['a', 'b']},
            {'value' : ['c', 'e']},
            {'value' : ['a', 'c', 'b']},   *
```

Comment: `first` is the sorting sort order?  How do you figure how 'e' should sort (it's not in `first`)?

Comment: Sorry if it's obvious, but I do not understand the relationship between first, second, and third at all.  None of them really look sorted, and they all have different sets of characters.  Can you provide some more details on exactly what you're trying to do?

Comment: I reckon OP wants to count *how many elements* from `first` each array has. So `third` has 3, 2 and 1 element from `first`. And that raises even more questions...

Comment: a reduce function would be better i guess

Comment: I have slightly changed the description of the problem

Comment: What does "match" between two disparate arrays mean?

Comment: why acb in first ab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a function `count(v)` that returns the number of elements that intersect between `first` and `v` which is a `second[i].value`.  Then `filter()` and `sort()` using the `count()` function:

```
var first = ['a', 'b', 'c',]
var second = [ 
            {'value' : ['a', 'b']},
            {'value' : ['c', 'e']},
            {'value' : ['a', 'c', 'b']},
            {'value' : ['f']}, 
          ]

const count = (v) => v.value.reduce((a, v) => a += first.includes(v), 0)

var third = second.
    filter(v => count(v) > 0).
    sort((a, b) => count(b) - count(a))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create a function that returns the number of matches you can use it to first filter out the ones with no matches and then use it to sort by the most matches.

```js
const numberOfMatches= (arr, from) => arr.filter(item => from.includes(item)).length;

var first = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var second = [ 
  {'value' : ['a', 'b']},
  {'value' : ['c', 'e']},
  {'value' : ['a', 'c', 'b']},
  {'value' : ['f']}, 
];

const result = second
  .filter(val => numberOfMatches(val.value, first))
  .sort((a, b) => numberOfMatches(b.value, first) - numberOfMatches(a.value, first));

console.log(result);
```